# Initialize On-Off toggle elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I have got a table of accounts and I want to be able to toggle them on/off using JQuery toggles. In the beginning I need to initialize the toggles each account (either they one account is set to on or off). I want to do this on page loading.

**My Jade template part:**

```
tbody
  each account in accounts
    tr
      td
        .col-sm-7.control-label
          div(class='toggle toggle-success', onload='initToggle(#{account.IsActive}, this)')
        | #{account.Id}
      td #{account.Email}
```

**My init toggle function:**

```
script.
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function initToggle(isActive, element)
    {
      if (isActive)
        element.toggles({'on': true});
      else
        element.toggles({'on': false});
    }
```

**My problem:**

If I use `onload=` for my function call I don't get an error at all. If I use the `onclick=`as function call, google chrome shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initToggle is not defined

**How would I properly initialize my on/off toggles?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the function is declared / scoped inside the "ready" callback.
To fix that, I would move the logic and let the javascript decides *when* init things:

**Jade part**

```
div(class='toggle toggle-success', data-is-active='#{account.IsActive}')
```

**Javascript part**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".toggle").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var isActive = $this.data("isActive") === "true";
    // or .data("is-active") for jQuery 2, see https://api.jquery.com/data/
    $this.toggles({'on': isActive});
  });
});
```

The jade side uses a [html data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store the information and the js side uses it when the document is ready.